# "We're sorry, but something went wrong." - right after deploying in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, apache2

I've just released my Rails 4.2.5 app in production, everything was working fine during development, once I put the secret key to `secret.yml`and restarted passenger, I got the typical error 500 message, but I can't tell from where it comes because `development.log` and `production.log` doesn't show anything at all.

This is the first time I release a raill app so I'm sadly a newbie in this domain even though everything went relatively fine until now, but I don't have any clue where to look at to solve the problem..

My server is on Debian 8, with Apache2 and passenger (if it can help)

Thank you in advance

**EDIT**

I think i found the problem, thanks to your help

```
App 25227 stderr: Started GET "/" for 92.90.21.174 at 2016-01-28 11:53:17 +0100
App 25227 stderr:
App 25227 stderr: Mysql2::Error (Access denied for user 'siteweb'@'localhost' (using password: NO)):
```

Just to be sure, does it mean that i didn't set any password to my database while I give one when I'm attempting to connect ?

Thank you again in advance

Comment: Does apache's log say anything?

Comment: It's possible that your user session got invalidated after you changed `secret.yml`. Try clearing your browser cookies.

Comment: The log will reveal all

Comment: can you post the logs

Comment: I updated the code, this is the only error i find, the others are about the resources loading, but i can't access to my ip/phpmyadmin, I get the error 500. I tried to edit my `database.yml` and to reboot the server, but it did nothing...